# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName CrudPU

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I need to perform test task for new job, but it seems I'm in a stupor.
I have some problems with persistence context. I use Glassfish 3 and this tutorial: http://uaihebert.com/?p=834

jdbc/CrudDS already configured on server and ping is successfull.
When application deployed, I see just ejb, web in "engines" column but no JPA engine.

Here is the Entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task implements Serializable {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

@Column(name="title")
private String title;

@Column(name="mail")
private String mail;

@Column(name="text")
private String text;

@Column(name="time")
private Date time;

@Column(name="interval")
private int interval;

@Column(name="repeats")
private int repeats;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Date getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getInterval() {
    return interval;
}

public void setInterval(int interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
}

public int getRepeats() {
    return repeats;
}

public void setRepeats(int repeats) {
    this.repeats = repeats;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId();
}


}
```

Here is my DAO abstract Class:

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> {

private final static String UNIT_NAME = "CrudPU";

@PersistenceContext(unitName = UNIT_NAME)
private EntityManager em;

private Class<T> entityClass;

public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

public void save(T entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}

protected void delete(Object id, Class<T> classe) {
    T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);

    em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
}

public T update(T entity) {
    return em.merge(entity);
}

public T find(int entityID) {
    return em.find(entityClass, entityID);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<T> findAll() {
    CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected T findOneResult(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    T result = null;

    try {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

        if (parameters != null && !parameters.isEmpty()) {
            populateQueryParameters(query, parameters);
        }

        result = (T) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while running query: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

private void populateQueryParameters(Query query, Map<String, Object> parameters) {

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
}
```

Extending of DAO class:

```
@Stateless 
public class TaskDAO extends GenericDAO<Task>{

public TaskDAO() {
    super(Task.class);
}

public void delete(Task task) {
    super.delete(task.getId(), Task.class);
}

}
```

Facade interface:

```
@Local
public interface TaskFacade {

public abstract void save(Task task);

    public abstract Task update(Task task);

    public abstract void delete(Task task);

    public abstract Task find(int entityID);

    public abstract List<Task> findAll();

}
```

... and it's implement:

```
@Stateless
public class TaskFacadeImpl implements TaskFacade {

    @EJB
    private TaskDAO taskDAO;

    public void save(Task task) {
        isTaskWithAllData(task);

        taskDAO.save(task);
    }

    public Task update(Task task) {
        isTaskWithAllData(task);

        return taskDAO.update(task);
    }

    public void delete(Task task) {
        taskDAO.delete(task);
    }

    public Task find(int entityID) {
        return taskDAO.find(entityID);
    }

    public List<Task> findAll() {
        return taskDAO.findAll();
    }

    private void isTaskWithAllData(Task task){
        boolean hasError = false;

        if(task == null){
            hasError = true;
        }

        if(task.getInterval() < 0){
            hasError = true;
        }

        if(task.getRepeats() < 0){
            hasError = true;
        }

        if (task.getMail() == null || "".equals(task.getMail().trim())){
            hasError = true;
        }

        if (hasError){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The task is missing data. Check the e-mail, it should have value. Interval and repeats should be >= 0 ");
        }
    }
}
```

And persistence.xml from /src/META-INF/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CrudPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/CrudDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And when I try to perform some operation ( save() ) I get an exception:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2314)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2096)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
at $Proxy235.save(Unknown Source)
at com.zhalostnikov.dao.__EJB31_Generated__TaskDAO__Intf____Bean__.save(Unknown Source)
at com.zhalostnikov.facade.TaskFacadeImpl.save(TaskFacadeImpl.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
at $Proxy236.save(Unknown Source)
at TestBean.doo(TestBean.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 32 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName CrudPU
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:132)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTxRequiredCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:152)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.doTransactionScopedTxCheck(EntityManagerWrapper.java:145)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:263)
at com.zhalostnikov.dao.GenericDAO.save(GenericDAO.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
... 69 more
```

It looks like persistence unit couldn't be found, but I can't find the reason.
Could enybody help me with it please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you double check where is persistence.xml located within your war file? It should be on myapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.

If you use standard maven layout, your persistence.xml should be on src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml within the source code project

Comment: I put persistence.xml fil in src/main/resources/, and found it in .war/WEB-INF/classes/ folder. Is it right?

Comment: Wrong. See my answer, should be src/main/resources/META-INF, and your resulting war should have the persistence.xml on .war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the next error occures when I tried to deploy: SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Comment: That's because you haven't added hibernate (or hibernate-entitymanager) jars to your classpath, and/or you're deploying to a container that doesn't come with hibernate

Comment: Thank you for that, normally my META-INF folder was working in the src/main/webapp directory but it didn't for one of my projects.